# Obscure reasons a file is read-only?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems

The Linux filesystem seems to have layers and layers of subtlety that I stumble upon case-by-case:

I'm interested in editing this file:

```
[user@box ~]$ ls -l /a/b/c/foo.bar
-rw-rwxr-x    1 user   user      144529 Jan 26  2018 /a/b/c/foo.bar
```

It looks like it should be writable by user `user` - true? But when I try to edit the file in vim, I get a "`W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file`" warning.

I know that file writability has a dependency on the permissions of its containing folder. I think the containing folder needs to have execute permission - true? I assume the required directory permission also extends all the way up to `/` - true?

It looks to me like the noted file's containing folder tree has execute permissions:

```
[user@box ~]$ ls -ld /a/b/c/                                                                                    
drwxrwxrwx    2 user   user       36864 Mar  5 17:50 /a/b/c/
[user@box ~]$ ls -ld /a/b/           
drwxrwxr-x    4 user   user        4096 Sep 22  2017 /a/b/
[user@box ~]$ ls -ld /a/                
drwxrwxr-x    9 user   user        4096 Sep 15  2017 /a/
[user@box ~]$ ls -ld /     
drwxr-xr-x   24 root   root           0 Aug 24 10:48 /
[user@box ~]$ whoami
user
```

As far as I can tell from the above, every directory in the relevant tree has execute permissions. At first, I was suspicious of whether it had to do with `/` being owned by `root`, but it has execute permission for "others". Plus, if there were issues related to `/` being owned by `root`, I imagine I'd have trouble writing files anywhere on the filesystem as a user other than `root`, but that is not the case.

Can anyone think of/identify other reasons why the noted file is considered read-only?

Comment: Is any part of the directory tree /a/b/c/ a separate partition than / ? `lsblk` would tell you if it is.

Comment: Did you start `vim` with the `-R` option or do you have `readonly`/`ro` set through either your `.vimrc` file or by a modeline in the file itself?

Comment: @Thegs - it looks like `lsblk` is not a supported command on the box on which I'm working - is there any other command that'd give equivalent information (I'm not familiar with partitions, so I've no clue what investigative commands are available)

Comment: @Kusalananda - I can confirm that `vim` was not started with `-R` and I'm pretty sure `vim` is not sourcing any file that specifies `readonly/ro` because I am able to edit other, unrelated, files. I'm not sure what you mean by "modeline" but it sounds like a string embedded within the file I want to edit...? If so, a case-insensitive `grep` on the file for "modeline" came back empty.

Comment: @StoneThrow `df` can also show what's mounted, there should be a column called "Mounted on" or something similar.

Comment: @StoneThrow A "modeline" is a line such as `# vim: ro` in the file. It may be used to set `vim` options specific to a file (like tab lengths etc., but also the `ro` option).  The line is usually at the start or end of the file.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I see, thank you; however a case-insensitive grep for "vim" in the file came back empty.

Comment: @Thegs - I think your suggestion dovetails into what Luciano answered below. When I ran `df` the output had the line "`/dev/sda1             79637648    884536  74707684   1% /a`". From there, I ran the `mount` command per Luciano's answer, and if I interpreted the output correctly it implied that the `/a/` directory is mounted to a read-only filesystem, so effectively that entire directory tree is read-only...? (my understanding of the relationship between partitions and filesystems is very rudimentary, so sorry if my terminology is awkward)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**First**  - you are with immutable flag set

```
chattr -i yourfilename
```

If immutable flag is set you cannot change the file. Remember that permissions did not override that behavior!

**Second,** check if the directory where file is, is **mounted in another disk or partition**, as read only, for that just type:

```
mount
```

(without arguments)

If you see something like your directory mounted as read-only there is the reason! Remount it as read-write to get lucky!

**Third - and most common**, you are just running a **filesystem with errors**, to correct that, you must backup what you can, reboot, then login in single mode and run:

```
mount #To determine how the partition is mounted
mount -o remount,ro /dev/sd(yourpartition) directory
fsck.ext4 /dev/sd(yourpartition)
```

(ext4 maybe need to be changed to your partition type)

Good Lucky!

Comment: I think you identified my problem: `chattr -i /a/b/c/foo.bar` came back with "`chattr: setting flags on /a/b/c/foo.bar: Read-only file system`" I then did `mount` and the output had the line "`/dev/sda1 on /a type ext4 (ro,noatime,barrier=1,data=ordered)`" -- does this mean that the entire `/a/` directory tree is effectively read-only?

Comment: Yes it means exactly that. ro "(ro," read-only. The causes may vary, if the partition is explicity mounted read-only by you for example, or falled-back to read-only due to filesystem errors. You can check if the partition has errors with dmesg | grep /dev/sda1 maybe you will see something like Uh! Oh! remounted read-only or something like that. To do the fsck you must use fsck.ext4 /dev/sda1. To just remount read-write if you dont have any errors mount -o remount,rw none /a

Comment: See my `bash` script https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld